# IDW10502: An MsalUiRequiredException was thrown due to a challenge for the user. No account or login hint was passed to the AcquireTokenSilent call

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, microsoft-graph-api

I am now caretaker of an inherited DotNet Core 3.1 MVC app which makes extensive use of MS Graph API calls and works perfectly.  Given this, I recently dared to create a new DotNet Core 3.1 MVC app and would like to incorporate MS Graph calls into the new app as well.  Not having much luck so far.

I am new to the MS Graph API and, admittedly, do not understand much of what I've found regarding the following error message:

Message:  IDW10502: An MsalUiRequiredException was thrown due to a challenge for the user.
Inner exception:  No account or login hint was passed to the AcquireTokenSilent call.

There are other posts on the web regarding this error message but the responses are widely varied and often lack any real value in terms of a solution.  I have no idea what these messages are indicating I should do.

My code (primarily adapted from the working project).........

```
Startup.cs 
    services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options))
        .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(Configuration, "AzureAd")
        .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
        .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
    ;

    services.AddGraphService(Configuration);
    services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
    {
        var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
           .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .Build();
        options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
    });

    services.AddRazorPages();
```

```
MyController.cs

public class MyController: BaseController
{
    private static IConfiguration appConfig;
    private readonly ITokenAcquisition tokenAcquisition;
    private readonly GraphSettings graphSettings;
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment hostingEnvironment;

    public MyController(IConfiguration configuration, ITokenAcquisition tokenAcquisition, IOptions<GraphSettings> graphSettingsValue, IWebHostEnvironment hosting) 
    {
        appConfig = configuration;
        this.tokenAcquisition = tokenAcquisition;
        this.graphSettings = graphSettingsValue.Value;
        this.hostingEnvironment = hosting;
    }

    async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        string[] scopes = new string[] { "User.Read", "User.ReadBasic.All", "User.Read.All", "User.ReadWrite", "User.ReadWrite.All" };
        User graphUser = await GetGraphUser(graphSettings, tokenAcquisition, scopes).ConfigureAwait(false);

        // stuff happens here//

        return View();
    }

    public async Task<User> GetGraphUser(GraphSettings graphSettings, ITokenAcquisition tokenAcquisition, string[] scopes)
    {
       GraphServiceClient graphClient = GetGraphServiceClient(graphSettings, tokenAcquisition, scopes);
        string selectedFields = "displayName,streetAddress,city,state,postalCode,businessPhones,mobilePhone,mail,userPrincipalName,id,appRoleAssignments,jobTitle,givenName,surname";

        // Retrieve user's [id] using the [objectidentifier] value from the User.Identities.Claims collection.
        string loggedInUserId = User.Identities.FirstOrDefault().Claims.Single(x => x.Type.Contains("objectidentifier")).Value;

        var graphUser1 = await graphClient.Users[loggedInUserId]
            .Request()
            .Select(selectedFields)
            .GetAsync()
            .ConfigureAwait(false);
        if (graphUser1 != null)
        {
                return graphUser1;
        }
    }

    public GraphServiceClient GetGraphServiceClient(GraphSettings graphSettings, ITokenAcquisition tokenAcquisition, string[] scopes, bool beta = false)
    {
        return GraphServiceClientFactory.GetAuthenticatedGraphClient(async () =>
        {
            string accessToken = await tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(scopes).ConfigureAwait(false);
            return accessToken;
        },
        graphSettings.GraphApiUrl);
    }
```

```
GraphServiceClientFactory.cs

namespace MyNamespace.Extensions
{
}
    public class GraphSettings
    {
        public string GraphApiUrl { get; set; }
        public string GraphApiBeta { get; set; }
    }

    public static class GraphServiceRegistration
    {
        public static void AddGraphService(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            services.Configure<GraphSettings>(configuration);
        }
    }

    public class GraphServiceClientFactory
    {
        public static GraphServiceClient GetAuthenticatedGraphClient(Func<Task<string>> acquireAccessToken, string baseUrl)
        {
            return new GraphServiceClient(baseUrl, new CustomAuthenticationProvider(acquireAccessToken));
        }
    }

    class CustomAuthenticationProvider : IAuthenticationProvider
    {
        public CustomAuthenticationProvider(Func<Task<string>> acquireTokenCallback)
        {
            acquireAccessToken = acquireTokenCallback;
        }

        private readonly Func<Task<string>> acquireAccessToken;

        public async Task AuthenticateRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage request)
        {
          **// ERROR IS THROWN HERE**  
          try {
              string accessToken = await acquireAccessToken.Invoke();
          }
          catch (Exception ex) {
              string msg = ex.Message;
          }
            // Append the access token to the request.
            request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
        }
    }
}
```

Any assistance/guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you're getting an MsalUiRequiredException was thrown due to a challenge for the user. You need to clear Cache or open the site in a Incognito tab

Comment: This was the solution for me

Answer (score 1):

I found a very simple solution which allowed me to resolve my issue.  Details are available from the the following Microsoft Tutorial:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/scenario-secure-app-access-microsoft-graph-as-user?source=recommendations&tabs=azure-resource-explorer

A minor modification to my Startup.cs file and the addition of the Microsoft.Identity.Web.MicrosoftGraph package had me back in business quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Im my case the graph call worked fine from within the controller or service, but threw this error when I called the graph in a controller attribute or custom policy handler.. In this instance I had to add a RejectSessionCookieWhenAccountNotInCacheEvents method [as detailed here](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/issues/13)

Answer (score 0):

For asp.net core MVC app integrating Azure AD, we need to do the following steps， more details can be seen in this [official sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/2-WebApp-graph-user/2-1-Call-MSGraph):

Creating azure ad application, add client secret and redirect URL, since you had a well working app, you must have had that azure ad app, pls don't forget to add another redirect url.

Obtain the azure ad app client id, client secret, tenant name/id, then in your new MVC project, open appsettings.json file and set value:

```
"AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "tenant_name.onmicrosoft.com",
    "TenantId": "tenant id",
    "ClientId": "Client Id, e.g. ba74781c2-53c2-442a-97c2-3d60re42f403]",
    "ClientSecret": "client secret",
  },
  "DownstreamApi": {
    "BaseUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0",
    "Scopes": "user.read"
  },
```

Going to `startup.cs`, add codes below into `ConfigureServices` method, and don't forget to add `app.UseAuthentication();` in `Configure` method.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI;
  
services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(Configuration)
        .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(new string[] { "user.read" })
       .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
{
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();
    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
})
// Add the Microsoft Identity UI pages for signin/out
.AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
```

Creating a sign in partial view `_LoginPartial.cshtml` in `Shared` folder:

```
@using System.Security.Principal

<ul class="navbar-nav">
@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
        <li class="nav-item">
            <span class="navbar-text text-dark">Hello @User.Identity.Name!</span>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="MicrosoftIdentity" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="SignOut">Sign out</a>
        </li>
}
else
{
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="MicrosoftIdentity" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="SignIn">Sign in</a>
        </li>
}
</ul>
```

Add this view to `_Layout.cshtml`:

[image]

These are the required packages:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI" Version="3.1.14" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Graph.Core" Version="2.0.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.MicrosoftGraph" Version="1.25.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI" Version="1.25.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="3.1.5" />
```

Add `[Authorize]` to the Home Controller,

```
private readonly GraphServiceClient _graphServiceClient;

public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger,GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient,)
{
    _logger = logger;
    _graphServiceClient = graphServiceClient;
}

public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    var user = await _graphServiceClient.Me.Request().GetAsync();
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply!!!  It appears your solution provides essentially the same remedy as the Microsoft Tutorial referenced in my answer, to add the Microsoft.Identity.Web.MicrosoftGraph package into the mix.  Thanks again!

Comment: thank you for replying to me : ) I vote your answer,